# Adding comma between two numbers

Tags: r

I have a data as below.

```
 0.0  5.0
 1.0  5.1
 2.0 13.3
 3.0 29.5
 4.0 44.4
 5.0 54.6
 6.0 63.5
 7.0 69.1
 8.0 73.9
 9.0 72.4
10.0 72.3
11.0 76.1
12.0 74.3
13.0 77.8
14.0 78.1
15.0 79.5
16.0 80.5
17.0 79.8
18.0 78.1
19.0 77.0
20.0 78.9
```

and I would like to add comma between two numbers such as

```
 0.0,  5.0
 1.0,  5.1
 2.0, 13.3
 3.0, 29.5
 4.0, 44.4
 5.0, 54.6
 6.0, 63.5
 7.0, 69.1
 8.0, 73.9
 9.0, 72.4
10.0, 72.3
11.0, 76.1
12.0, 74.3
13.0, 77.8
14.0, 78.1
15.0, 79.5
16.0, 80.5
17.0, 79.8
18.0, 78.1
19.0, 77.0
20.0, 78.9
```

Do you have any idea how to add a comma between two numbers?
thanks

Comment: do you want to generate this output on screen? or to a file (a `.csv` file, for example)?

Comment: by you have "data" you mean that in a string variable or in a text file or where

Comment: Is this a `data.frame` we're talking about?  Do you want a column of commas in between? Or included in the first column?  Need input. Keep in mind that this may change the `class` of at least one of the columns.

Comment: If this is pre-reading into R, you could easily do this with regex find/replace in Sublime Text (or other text editors). If it's a huge file, one *could* use R for this, but even `sed` would be a better choice (and there's a Windows `sed`, too)

Comment: Barranka I would like to save this output in the txt file in order to draw a graph.

Comment: Hi I am sorry that I made you confused.I have saved those result in txt.file and I would like to add a comma between two variable using r program. thanks

Comment: hi, as a relatively new user you might not realize that you can comment, upvote (when you have 15 reputation), or accept answers to your questions if you feel an answer has addressed your concern. You've asked 4 or 5 questions and got 4 or 5 answers and the site works better when there's feedback from the person who asks the question. Please see meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/165400 for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `d` is the data, you can use `write.table` with `sep = ", "`.  Here are a few lines:

```
> write.table(d, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = ", ")
0, 5
1, 5.1
2, 13.3
3, 29.5
4, 44.4
5, 54.6
6, 63.5
7, 69.1
```

Comment: Maybe make `sep=", "` to include a space after each comma.

Comment: Good call @JoshO'Brien.  Changed.